# JQUERY: Add more item when insert new data

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp-1.3

I am developing the app using CakePHP 1.3 Now I want to make the "Insert function" to add new user into database. I have 2 fields user & pass to insert. But I not only insert 1 user, I want insert one or multiple user (optional). If I want to add more user I will click to "add more" to add new field in view.

In cakephp, it required when we want to insert a array with multiple data. The field name will be define as:

```
<?php
   echo $this->Form->input('Modelname.0.fieldname');
   echo $this->Form->input('Modelname.1.fieldname');
?>
```

and in view will be:

```
<input type="text" id="Modelname0Fieldname" name="**data[Modelname][0][fieldname]**">
<input type="text" id="Modelname1Fieldname" name="**data[Modelname][1][fieldname]**">
```

My question is: Does JQuery have some function to add new element and how can I increase the index number follow the pattern above **data[Modelname][0][fieldname]**

Thank for your view and suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created this code, here it is, I've tested it and it works

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbxVQG

```js
var $insertBefore = $('#insertBefore');
var $i = 0;
$('#plusButton').click(function(){
  $i = $i+1;
  $('<br><div class="Index">User N. ' + $i + '</div><br>Username:<br><input type="text" id="Modelname' + $i + 'Fieldname" name="**data[Modelname][' + $i + '][fieldname]**"><br>Password:<br><input type="text" id="Modelname' + $i + 'Password" name="**data[Modelname][' + $i + '][Password]**"><br>').insertBefore($insertBefore);
});
```

```css
#Userlist{
  border-style:solid;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
.Index{
  background-color:grey;
  text-align:left;
}
#plusButton {
  background-color:green;
  color: white;
  font-size:1.9em;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Add New Users</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>  
<body>  
  <form action="your-script.php" method="post" id="Userlist">
    <div class="Index">User N. 0</div>
     Username:<br>
      <input type="text" id="Modelname0Fieldname" name="**data[Modelname][0][fieldname]**"">
      <br>Password:<br>
      <input type="text" id="Modelname0Password" name="**data[Modelname][0][Password]**">
    <br>
    <div id="insertBefore"></div>
    <br><br><input type="submit" value="Add User">
  </form>
  <div id="plusButton">+</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

some important notes:

1- The div who's `id="insertBefore"` is just to tell jQuery where to put the new duplicated fields.

2- The jQuery code works with an index variable (`$i`) that starts in 0 and gets incremented by 1 on each new click on the "+" button (so the first time you click, it should get to 1)

3- The original Form's code (where value is 0 by default) is printed everytime the + button is clicked, but replacing each `0` in the html code by `'+$i+'`

3.2 - If you make some changes to the code of your form, by this method, you should change the javascript code as well. I know it's not an elegant solution to do this, but it shouldn't be so difficult either, just remember to copy the exact html code, delete all `intro`'s and replace all `0`'s with `'+$i+'`

4- The "Index N." div is just keeping track of the user's number, you could put your own text there, like "User Nº 0" and in the jQuery code replace the 0 with the value of `$i`

5- You could put a limit to the number of users (example:10) that can be added by creating an `if($i<10){}` variable inside the `.click()` function

Answer (score 1):

Just write a jQuery code to append a user field. and also send data-id to the javascript.

Let say for example. in your form.

```
<div id="segment">
    $this->Form->input('User.1.name',array('class'=>'user','data-id'=>1));
</div>
```

in jquery.you can have a function like this on click of add user,

```
var lastid = parseInt($('.user:last').attr('data-id');
var newid = lastid+1;

var input = "<input name='data[User][" + newid + "][name]' class='user' id='user-" + newid + "' data-id='" + newid + "' type='text'><br/>";
$('#segement').append(input);
```

> Note that double check the input string, I might miss a quote or
>   anything.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all answers about this, I was not test your code but I found the way to append and increase the index number too. When I have time, I will research about your code.

My code is follow this thread http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery. He made it easily to understand.

The JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>
```

The demo you can see in that link above.

More thank for everybody again.