# Multiple values inside form php/query

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, forms

Before I start, I want to say that I used the search function but none of the other questions helped me.

I found a code that fits what I need ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26900723/jquery-add-more-item-when-insert-new-data)) but there is a is when I try to retrieve the values.

// Edit

Assuming that i'am using exactly the some code, how to retrieve the values?

The code above is to show what happen when user click in the plus button.

```
<form method='post' name='form'>
<input type="text" name="username[0]'>
<input type="password" name="password[0]">

// new added fiels using the jquery
<input type="text" name="username[1]'>
<input type="password" name="password[1]">
</form>
```

Using a form like this, how to retrieve the values one by one?

```
<?php if (isset($POST['submit'])) { // what to do here? }?>
```

I ask this question because I want to store the values on a sql database, and I need the separated values like:

User 1 - user & pass

User 2 - user & pass

To use this on a php function that receive the `$user` and `$pass` values.

Comment: using `$_POST["username"]` will give u an array of the usernames that have been input in the form, same goes for password

Comment: *"I have this question because i want to store the values on a sql database"* - Is it relevant to the question? Should the good people also provide code for that? Question's a tad unclear. Plus, `$POST['button']` is failing you for a few reasons, if that's your actual code.

Comment: and relevance to the jquery tag is what?

Comment: and I am out of this question as a "lending hand".

Comment: @Fred-ii-, No, if you see the link i posted inside the (here), you'll understand the jquery, its because the main code use jquery to dynamically add input values, thats why.
And i added the information about the sql database because i need separated values to store on different columns.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, oh! now i understand, fixed my question, it is assuming that i use the same code, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form method='post' name='form'>
<input type="text" name="username['username'][]'>
<input type="password" name="password['password'][]">
// new added fiels using the jquery
<input type="text" name="['username'][]'>
<input type="password" name="password['password'][]">
<input type = "submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$postData = $_POST;  
for($i = 0; $i < count($postData);$i++){
    $username = $postData['username'][$i];
    $password = $postData['password'][$i];
}
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Making this way it worked exactly the way i wanted, thank you so much!

Comment: Never realized that calling $_POST it retrieve all the post values. Thanks for the answer! I selected this as the answer because it shows the full code but @Felippe-Duarte works as well too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different names:

```
<form method='post' name='form'>
    <input type="text" name="username_1">
    <input type="password" name="password_1">

    // new added fiels using the jquery
    <input type="text" name="username_2">
    <input type="password" name="password_2">
</form>

<?php
    $username_1 = $_POST['username_1'];
    ....
```

Or, you can use arrays like this:

```
<form method='post' name='form'>
    <input type="text" name="username[]">
    <input type="password" name="password[]">

    // new added fiels using the jquery
    <input type="text" name="username[]">
    <input type="password" name="password[]">
</form>
```

Your var $_POST['username'] and $_POST['password'] will be arrays. You can iterate the way you want:

`foreach($_POST['username'] as $username)`

`for($i = 0, $c = count($_POST['username']); $i < $c; $i++)`

Comment: This will get messy quick with dynamically added inputs. Better to stick with the array

Comment: @JeffPuckettII, yep, using array make it more clear to understand and manage after.

Answer (score 0):

You can echo out each value of the array, or use it any way you want

```
foreach ($_POST['username'] as $user)
  echo $user;
```

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii- for catching my blind copy-paste

Answer (score 0):

You could use separate arrays for every user - pass you need. For example:

```
<form method='post' name='form'>
<input type="text" name="user[0]['user']'>
<input type="password" name="user[0]['password']">

// new added fiels using the jquery
<input type="text" name="user[1]['user']>
<input type="password" name="user[1]['password']>
</form>
```

You read it from php with something like this.

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['user'])) {
  foreach($_POST['user'] as $user){
    $username = $user['user'];
    $password = $user['password'];
    //save into database
}

}?>
```

And then save into database. You could use php pdo.
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward using PHP and HTML.  You can look at some examples and documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php.

You use an HTML form like this:

```
<form name="form1" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username1" />
    <input type="password" name="password1" />

    <input type="text" name="username2" />
    <input type="password" name="password2" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then you would use PHP to get the values like this:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $user1 = $_POST['username1'];
        $pass1 = $_POST['password1'];
        $user2 = $_POST['username2'];
        $pass2 = $_POST['password2'];
    }
?>
```

Of course, use `isset()` to make sure each username and password is set also, but you get the point.

Comment: *"Of course, use isset() to make sure each username and password"* - `empty()` is better ;-)

Comment: Wouldn't it be identical in this case, since the POST variables (if empty) wouldn't have been sent at all?